# MBR Within not accurate in mysql

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I have been using the MBRWithin function for quite a lot of times. Suddenly I notice on google map this `POINT(101.11857 4.34475)` is out of the geo fence which I specify but it still give a value of 1 in mysql any reason or tweaking need to be done?

`SELECT MBRWithin(GeomFromText('POINT(101.11857  4.34475)'),GeomFromText('POLYGON((101.12112522125244 4.3531723687957164,101.11846446990967 4.351417913665312,101.13138198852539 4.336397898951581,101.13477230072021 4.33211863778494,101.14065170288086 4.321933898868271,101.14992141723633 4.306699328215635,101.15455627441406 4.30978050198082,101.1397933959961 4.334600612212089,101.12112522125244 4.3531723687957164,101.12112522125244 4.3531723687957164))')) As geoFenceStatus`

Answer (score 6):

MySQL 5.6.1 and later have **exact geometry algorithms** in addition to the earlier functions that only operated on MBR.

You can use `ST_WITHIN` rather than `MBR_WITHIN`. See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries). Like this

```
SELECT ST_Within(GeomFromText('POINT(101.11857 4.34475)'),
  GeomFromText('POLYGON((101.12112522125244 4.3531723687957164,101.11846446990967 
    4.351417913665312,101.13138198852539 4.336397898951581,101.13477230072021 
    4.33211863778494,101.14065170288086 4.321933898868271,101.14992141723633 
    4.306699328215635,101.15455627441406 4.30978050198082,101.1397933959961 
    4.334600612212089,101.12112522125244 4.3531723687957164,101.12112522125244 
    4.3531723687957164))')) As geoFenceStatus
```

Comment: Mark thank you for information. The problem now currently we are running 5.0.77 on centos which according to centos guys is stable at per installation and do not advice to upgrade to further version. So what is you opinion on that?  Thank you.

Comment: You will have to go with Kaivosukeltaja's answer if you can't use a later version of MySQL

Comment: I am ok to use but you know centos recommends what is stable as per their opinion so I am quite stuck I need the functionality but is only newer version has it so you too agree on Kaivo's suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Kaivo your codes work properly I have already solve the phpMYAdmin already but onething it takes some time. Using mbr is 0.0004sec meanwhile your GISWithin takes 0.0024Sec any more tweaking can be done to make it faster?

Comment: @newbie You should put that comment on Kaivo's answer. He might not notice it here, on my answer. Also if Kaivo's answer has been helpful, you should upvote it (click the "up arrow") and consider accepting it as the answer to your question (click the "hollow tick").

Answer (score 1):

`MBRWithin()` will return results based on the minimum bounding rectangle of it's parameters. Your polygon contains both larger and smaller values for both coordinates than the point, so it will be within the polygon's MBR.

MySQL has no built-in point in polygon algorithm, so you'll either have to roll your own or find one elsewhere. [This one](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,286574,286574) seems to be a good candidate.

Comment: So what is the accurate solution to say that indeed the point is in the polygon or not? Because when I draw the on map both the point is out of the geo fence so what is the solution to it?

Comment: I have also try MBRContains it give me the same results.

Comment: @newbie14: All MBR functions use the minimum bounding rectangle instead of actual polygon data. I updated my answer with a link worth checking out.

Comment: I saw your link how slow will this be compare to pure MBRWithin based on your test? So I must build stored function is it any other work around? Thank you.

Comment: @newbie14: I haven't tested it myself but it should be as fast for points that would return 0 with `MBRWithin` as using the MBR functions, since it first checks if the point is within the polygon's bounding rectangle. If it is, the further checks will be quite a bit more cpu intensive. This may or may not be a problem, depending on the amount of rows in your database.

Comment: Ok kaivo I will give a try actually I very new to stored procedures. Just give some hints. What I will do is go to my phpmyadmin and run your script am I right? Then how check if there any error. Thereafter all the script just like any other query am I right?

Comment: @newbie14: Yes, run the script in the console or phpMyAdmin, up until the example. Then replace MBRWithin with GISWithin and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Kaivo I copied your whole script from DELIMITER // till here DELIMITER ; then I press Go in my phpmyadmin I do not seem to get any message. So when I put query in every thing same just replaced the MBRWithin with GISWithin it tells me the function does not exist? Any reason for this?

Comment: MySQL 5.6.1 and later **do** have exact polygon functions. See my answer

Comment: Hi Kaivo any help please why is your function not running well any reason for it? Thank you.

Comment: It could be for a lot of different reasons. If you can't solve it, you should probably open a new question about it - and maybe accept some answers to your previous questions to raise the motivation to answer.

Comment: Hi Kaivo your codes work properly I have already solve the phpMYAdmin already but onething it takes some time. Using mbr is 0.0004sec meanwhile your GISWithin takes 0.0024Sec any more tweaking can be done to make it faster?

Comment: MBR calculations are inherently a lot faster, because they are a lot simpler. That's why `GISWithin` (not mine, by the way) first checks the MBR before proceeding to more complex calculations.

Comment: Ok so there is no choice right off course need more accuracy will involve more complex calculation is that what you are trying to tell me. Do you think by index will help a bit on the speed?

Comment: Indexes don't apply to this situation because you're not selecting anything from a table, only doing calculations.

Comment: Yes true also agree with u so other room for improvement have to accept the time then.